Incompatibility with \vspace and \multicolumn in table-tabular enviroment?
I have problems with vertical space options when using tabular environment, i.e. \vspace does not work at all at the last line (after \bottomrule), but it does in the middle! (after \midrule. It has no sense! It turns out a big space appear between table and the last line (which is a kind of note), that's why I use \vspace{-10pt}, but it does not work with \multicolumn option (activate it and deactivate \flushleft option to check what I mean).
Here is MWE (I hope I did not forget any option)
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace,parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,siunitx,bm}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    
\begin{table}[htb]
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small}
    \caption{Caption example.} \vspace{-9pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \small
    \centering
    %\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{C{2.3cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}}    
    \toprule[0.8pt]
     \textbf{Params.} & & \textbf{ZSimpWin} & & \textbf{DE} & & \textbf{SaDE} & & \textbf{EA4eig} \\ 
     \midrule[0.8pt]
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textit{HP-35651}+\textit{UP-26030}}\vspace{4pt} \\
     $R_0$ & & $1.981\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $215.64$ & & $215.65$ & & $215.65$ \\
     $R_1$ & & $193.30$ & & $9474.68$ & & $9475.90$ & & $9475.90$ \\
     $R_2$ & & $2376.0$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_3$ & & $3.183\cdot10^{4}$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ \\
     $Q_1$ & & $9.800\cdot10^{-8}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ \\
     $n_1$ & & $0.6944$ & & $0.6818$ & & $0.6818$ & & $0.6818$ \\
     $Q_2$ & & $1.123\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $7.355\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $7.356\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $7.356\cdot10^{-5}$ \\
     $n_2$ & & $0.6130$ & & $0.7606$ & & $0.7606$ & & $0.7606$ \\
     $Q_3$ & & $2.048\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ \\
     $n_3$ & & $0.8037$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ \\
     \emph{FO} & & $2.2802\cdot10^{7}$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ \\
     \midrule[0.5pt]
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textit{HP-35651}+\textit{LP-45551}}\vspace{4pt} \\
     $R_0$ & & $1.354\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $306.02$ & & $306.02$ & & $306.02$ \\
     $R_1$ & & $337.80$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_2$ & & $6.218\cdot10^{4}$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_3$ & & $41.41$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ \\
     $Q_1$ & & $5.462\cdot10^{-6}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ \\
     $n_1$ & & $0.4015$ & & $0.6569$ & & $0.6569$ & & $0.6569$ \\
     $Q_2$ & & $1.668\cdot10^{4}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ \\
     $n_2$ & & $0.6307$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ \\
     $Q_3$ & & $1.325\cdot10^{-11}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ \\
     $n_3$ & & $0.9935$ & & $0.9942$ & & $0.9942$ & & $0.9942$ \\
     \emph{FO} & & $2.6095\cdot10^{7}$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ \\
     \bottomrule[0.8pt] \vspace{-10pt} \\
       %\multicolumn{9}{l}{\small{$R_i$ / \unit{\Omega.cm^2}; $Q_i$ / \unit{s^{n}.\Omega^{-1}.cm^{-2}}}}
    \end{tabular}%
    \vspace{-10pt}
    \flushleft        {\hspace{0.5cm} \small{$R_i$ / \unit{\Omega.cm^2}; $Q_i$ / \unit{s^{n}.\Omega^{-1}.cm^{-2}}}}
    %}
    \label{tab:a-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}

As you can see, I had to take an alternative way with \flushleft, but the option I want to use is the las \multicolumn which is commented. I don't understand why it doesn't work. It does work in other part of the table! Why is this happening?

you didn't test your example.

Guess: \\ after \bottomrule is nonsense. AFAIK it would add another (empty) row. And maybe you want a \midrule instead of a \bottomrule, but currently I cannot test.

@cabohah yes, I was making some test to try out options, but I forgot to delete it. Anyway, it seems has no effect. I use \bottomrule because it is the end of the table, what I added beleo is a kind of note for the units. Anyway, I tried to use \midrule instead of \bottomrule and it didn't work. This is a table from my work, and there is plenty of packages loaded. I will add the list of all packages.

@UlrikeFischer If you mean If I testet in the same way that is posted, then you are right. I will add all the packages loaded to my document.

@AnibalMarrero Please don't add all packages used in a document. Add only the packages needed to make for a minimal working example. Adding a bunch of not needed packages is almost as uneloquent as a not compiling example because of missing packages.

@cabohah I know, that is why I added what I considered the minimun packages and options and new commands needed for the example. I am not sure why it is not working for you.

@AnibalMarrero You don't know it, because you've not tested it. Please, see the link in my comments for more information.

@cabohah Please, check the post. It should work now (I have tested).

@AnibalMarrero Not perfect, but better.

As told in a comment, you want \midrule instead of \bottomrule, because syntactical it is not a bottom rule, but a rule between two table rows. Usually I would suggest to use \heavyrulewidth as optional argument to print it with the same thickness as a \bottomrule. But because you are already using another width, just use the same optional argument you are already using for your \bottomrule:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace,parskip}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small,aboveskip=0pt}
    \caption{Caption example.}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \small
    \centering
    %\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{C{2.3cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}C{0.15cm}C{2.0cm}}    
    \toprule[0.8pt]
     \textbf{Params.} & & \textbf{ZSimpWin} & & \textbf{DE} & & \textbf{SaDE} & & \textbf{EA4eig} \\ 
     \midrule[0.8pt]
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textit{HP-35651}+\textit{UP-26030}}\vspace{4pt} \\
     $R_0$ & & $1.981\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $215.64$ & & $215.65$ & & $215.65$ \\
     $R_1$ & & $193.30$ & & $9474.68$ & & $9475.90$ & & $9475.90$ \\
     $R_2$ & & $2376.0$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ & & $2.184\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_3$ & & $3.183\cdot10^{4}$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ & & $5.0\cdot10^5$ \\
     $Q_1$ & & $9.800\cdot10^{-8}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.061\cdot10^{-4}$ \\
     $n_1$ & & $0.6944$ & & $0.6818$ & & $0.6818$ & & $0.6818$ \\
     $Q_2$ & & $1.123\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $7.355\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $7.356\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $7.356\cdot10^{-5}$ \\
     $n_2$ & & $0.6130$ & & $0.7606$ & & $0.7606$ & & $0.7606$ \\
     $Q_3$ & & $2.048\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $3.765\cdot10^{-2}$ \\
     $n_3$ & & $0.8037$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ \\
     \emph{FO} & & $2.2802\cdot10^{7}$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ & & $8.3585\cdot10^6$ \\
     \midrule[0.5pt]
     \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textit{HP-35651}+\textit{LP-45551}}\vspace{4pt} \\
     $R_0$ & & $1.354\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $306.02$ & & $306.02$ & & $306.02$ \\
     $R_1$ & & $337.80$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ & & $1.351\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_2$ & & $6.218\cdot10^{4}$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ & & $3.854\cdot10^4$ \\
     $R_3$ & & $41.41$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ & & $1.0\cdot10^5$ \\
     $Q_1$ & & $5.462\cdot10^{-6}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ & & $1.506\cdot10^{-4}$ \\
     $n_1$ & & $0.4015$ & & $0.6569$ & & $0.6569$ & & $0.6569$ \\
     $Q_2$ & & $1.668\cdot10^{4}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ & & $8.469\cdot10^{-5}$ \\
     $n_2$ & & $0.6307$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ & & $1.0$ \\
     $Q_3$ & & $1.325\cdot10^{-11}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ & & $2.361\cdot10^{-2}$ \\
     $n_3$ & & $0.9935$ & & $0.9942$ & & $0.9942$ & & $0.9942$ \\
     \emph{FO} & & $2.6095\cdot10^{7}$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ & & $1.5573\cdot10^6$ \\
     \midrule[0.8pt]
     \multicolumn{9}{l}{$R_i$ / \unit{\Omega.cm^2}; $Q_i$ / \unit{s^{n}.\Omega^{-1}.cm^{-2}}}
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:a-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Note, that I've also removed some unused packages. Additionally I've replaced the \vspace after the \caption{…} by an additional setting at your \captionsetup. And I've removed a useless setting of \arraystretch, because it used the default. And I've removed as \small inside your \multicolumn, mainly because there is already a \small in the table environment and so the whole tabularx is \small. Nevertheless, please note, \small does not have an argument. So I've also removed a unnecessary group.

Thank you. There is still too much to learn. Since there are a lot of tables in my work, I use the same "template" for tables, and sometimes there are options that become useless, like \arraystretch in this case. I will take into account all your advises. Thanks a lot.
